# Proving that the Galois group of minimal polynomial of constructible number is a power of $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I was trying to understand whether a real number has degree which is power of 2 over rationals is constructible. Then I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126788/converse-of-the-theorem-lf-a-real-number-c-is-constructible-then-c-is-alge). But I am having trouble in understanding why this statement has to be true.

**The order of the Galois group of minimal polynomial of constructible number is a power of $2$**

If some one can give any hint as to why this is true it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www2.math.uu.se/~svante/papers/sjN8.pdf

The main job is done, where ii) --> v) is shown.

Comment: What you have written doesn't make sense, happymath. A group isn't a number. A group can't be a power of 2. What you probably mean is that the *order* of the Galois group is a power of 2.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for pointing that out I have edited it

Comment: @MooS thanks for the reference